# Ag-grid render multiple rows in a cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm new to Ag-grid(React version) and I encountered a problem in rendering multiple rows in a cell with Ag-Grid.

Here is what we've done by React Table but we want to do the same in the Ag-grid React version.
[image: What we have done by React Table]

Does anyone know how can I do this?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this documentation: [Row Spanning Complex Example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-spanning/#row-spanning-complex-example)

You can use `rowSpan` property of `ColDef` while providing values for your `ColDef`.
Provide `rowSpan` `1` for the two columns (2nd and 3rd visible in the screenshot), conditionally `1` or `2` for the 4th and `2` for the others.

```
colDef = [
  { field: 'field1', rowSpan: 2, /* other props */ },
  { field: 'field2', rowSpan: 1, /* other props */ },
  { field: 'field3', rowSpan: 1, /* other props */ },
  { field: 'field4', /* other props */, 
    rowSpan: (params) => {
      return  // your condition which decides rowSpan
    }
  },
  { field: 'field5', rowSpan: 2, /* other props */ },
  { field: 'field6', rowSpan: 2, /* other props */ }
];
```

[ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) Row spanning also has some limitations. Make sure you check this out as well: [Constraints with Row Spanning](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-spanning/#constraints-with-row-spanning)